# Android spinner with button and TOAST

Tags: java, android, button, spinner, toast

I am having a problem with my code that is supposed to display a toast when a button is clicked.

```
public TextView textView,textView2;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);


}
public void start(View view) {

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I do not know why the Toast message does not display and the program crashes when pressing the button.

This is my spinner in `activity_main.xml`

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="73dp"
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:entries="@array/jednostki"/>
```

button in xml

```
<Button
    android:text="Start"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="71dp"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:onClick="start"/>
```

and array with item

```
<string-array name="jednostki">
    <item>Celsjusze</item>
    <item>Farenheity</item>
    <item>Kelwiny</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: The xml file would also be helpful. Is the "start" method the onClickListener for the button?

Comment: Show your xml file.

Answer (score 2):

It looks as though you have not populated the spinner via an ArrayAdapter as shown in the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html). So unless you used the xml attribute android:entries="@array/array_name" method of populating the spinner (which we cannot see), then when you call spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() it will throw a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it all wrong. try this spinner in java class only. try this for example

```
final Spinner spinner=findViewById(R.id.home_spiner);
    final String[] items = new String[]{"AddCustomer","EditCustomer","AssignCustomer","RemoveCustomer"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and now make a button and use toast to show the values

```
 btn_select.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String str=spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

            Toast.makeText(SalesManagerActivity.this,str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're using unpopulated spinner. You need to use the `spinner2` instead of `spinner`. So, change your code to following:

```
// You should move the spinner variable here to 
// make it variable class scope.
Spinner spinner, spinner2;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
   spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
}

public void start(View view) {
  Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition()), 
                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```